# Rails: Run initializer before creating classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeresource, initializer

Basically I have an `initializer class` at `RAILS_ROOT/config/initialiers/app_constant.rb` to make everything easy to control.

```
class AppConstant
  APIURL = 'http://path.to.api'
end
```

And in the `RAILS_ROOT/model/user.rb`, I have the settings:

```
class User < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = AppConstant::APIURL
end
```

And when run `rails s`, I got the following error

```
<class:User>: uninitialized constant User::AppConstant::APIURL
```

I know that the problem is because Rails run Initializers after creating the Classes. Is there any way to make some Initializers run before Rails setup it classes?

---

Finally this problem is solved by adding `require "#{Rails.root}\conf\initializers\app_constant.rb"` to the `application.rb` which is loaded right before Rails loads models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have code run before Rails itself is loaded, put it above `require 'rails/all'` in `config/application.rb`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried with global scope `::` but it does not work. The problem is that, when Rails generates class `User`, class `AppConstant` isn't initialized. But I don't know how to make class `AppConstant` get initialized before it reads `User` class

Comment: You are right, finally I have to do this way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to wrap the constant in a method so it is not evaluated when the class is loaded, but only later when the method is called:

```
def self.site
  AppConstant::APIURL
end
```

If it needs to be settable as well:

```
def self.site=(url)
  @site = url
end

def self.site
  @site ||= AppConstant::APIURL
end
```